# System Updates List in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have 12.04 installed on my main machine, and also inside a VM using VMWare.  Both installations are identical.  I have noticed that when I do updates, I get different updates on both installations.  Why is that?  Also is there a way to see the a list of all the updates that have been downloaded?  Thanks

Comment: both using same server ?

Comment: Yes, both are using the same server.

Comment: I was told that even if you do not use the same server,  you would still get the same updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah you can see what you have installed , open software-center > history > Updates will gives the information of what you have installed through the updates .